# On the SE app, meta sites show as 'Unknown Site'

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange-mobile-app

The android App is showing this for Meta Sites:

[image: SE Site selection in-app showing 'Unknown Site']

And the app crashes if you click on it.

Comment: This issue is known and has been reported on the https meta https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292460/214193

Comment: *[status-completed]* - This was a temporary glitch caused by the move to HTTPS, and as discussed below  - logging out and back in fixes the issue permanently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of workarounds according to comments on the HTTPS discussion over on Meta.SE (linked above by @Unionhawk), you can try manually removing and re-adding the affected site(s), or even simply logging out and back in to the app:

> ...log out completely in the app and log back in (it requests the list of all sites from the Stack Exchange API on login).
>   <sub>– Kasra Rahjerdi ♦ [Mar 16 at 19:23](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time/292460#comment950071_292460)</sub>

Comment: Simply editing the list worked for me (I removed a different pinned site without  touching the meta sites).